# "Will have heard by now" sounds like bad usage to me; what is your opinion?

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, modal-verbs, perfect-aspect, deontic-vs-epistemic

I posted the question here

https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/295727/bad-usage-of-will-have

but it was closed due to insufficient details or clarity. I'm trying here.

---

The following sounds wrong to me; what do you think:

1. "As you will have heard, Aotearoa New Zealand will remain at alert level 4 until at least 11.59 pm on Friday 27 August."
2. "As you will have no doubt heard, there are two more confirmed cases of COVID-19 in Wellington today, bringing the total number in the region to eight."

Why I think it's wrong. 'Will have' should be used to reference a point in the future:

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/future-perfect-simple-i-will-have-worked-eight-hours

That's not the case in both sentences. Their meaning is:

- As you probably have heard by now, ...
- As you must have heard, ...

---

I got an opinion:

> both of them are fine, grammatically.
>
> "as you will have heard"  - referring to the past from the point in
> the future when the reader is reading (which is in the future relative
> to the time of writing).
>
> "As you will have no doubt heard,"   is the same, with the extra
> assertion that the writer has no doubt that the reader will have
> heard.

I don't agree with it. It's not snail mail: by the time you get this letter, you will have heard... It's email: you get it immediately, and I'm assuming you are reading it now, and I'm expressing myself as if I'm speaking to you in person.

Comment: Related, including possible duplicates: [0](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/421113), [1](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/413188), [2](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/347528), [3](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/336493), [4](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/503966), [5](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/553000), [6](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/465378), [7](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/430023), [8](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/63228), [9](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/411621), [10](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/115478).

Comment: It took me time to go over it, but yes, it covers it, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

"Will" can refer to the future but it can also refer to what is likely

will modal verb (LIKELY)

(also 'll)
used to refer to what is likely:
That'll be Scott at the door.
That'll be his mother with him.
As you all will know, election day is next week.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/will

So the quotations are correct and mean that it is likely that the addressee will have heard.

Comment: I realize that you yourself mustᴱᵖⁱˢᵗᵉᵐⁱᶜ know this already, but for the record and for the OP who still mustᴰᵉᵒⁿᵗⁱᶜ study these matters, a sentence like *“He willᴱᵖⁱˢᵗᵉᵐⁱᶜ have finished that last week”* is a statement about the past, not one about the future. It is a **modal perfect** in the ***epistemic modality*** of probabilities rather than in the ***deontic modality*** of permissions the way it is in the first but not the second clause of *“If you willᴰᵉᵒⁿᵗⁱᶜ have a seat, we willᴱᵖⁱˢᵗᵉᵐⁱᶜ be able to get started”.* None of these are in a tense; they're modals, including modal perfects.